# How to group time by period of seconds (MS Access) - Conflation

Tags: sql, ms-access

I work with a large dataset that I need to conflate within a specified time window.
For instance, some rows from the dataset :

```
symbol LAST_TRADE_TIME       CUR    BID     OFFER   VOLUME
DBK     2010-12-05 11:34:57   38    37.99   38      0
DBK     2010-12-05 11:34:57   38    37.99   38      0
DBK     2010-12-05 11:34:57   38    37.99   38      100
DBK     2010-12-05 11:34:58   38    37.99   38.005  0
```

What I intend to do retrieve a small number of rows (time slices). Each of them represent a period of 300 seconds:

```
SELECT Min(LAST_TRADE_TIME) AS ConflatedDate, Min(CUR) 
FROM MYTABLE
GROUP BY DateDiff("s",@StartDate,LAST_TRADE_TIME)/300;
```

I should get a date and a CUR every 300 seconds

If the use of datadiff does the job in sql server, in Ms ACCESS it returns total non sense to me.

`ConflatedDate          Expr1001
12/5/2010 9:34:56 AM    38.2
12/5/2010 9:34:57 AM    38.2
12/5/2010 9:34:58 AM    38.2
12/5/2010 9:35:08 AM    38.2
12/5/2010 9:35:13 AM    38.19
12/5/2010 9:35:14 AM    38.19
12/5/2010 9:35:16 AM    38.19
12/5/2010 9:35:18 AM    38.2`

As you can see above, no group by is done on time.
Can someone help me here and tell what is wrong with this query in MS ACCESS?   Or what to do to group by period?

Many many thx
Jerome

Comment: @StartDate "variable" is not valid in MS-Access unless its already defined as parameter above select statement.

Comment: agreed. @StartDate would be a variable which value is passed through manually. It represents the first datetime of  the data subset from where I want the conflation to start. I

Comment: you are looking to group "EVERY 300" minutes but divide will return all sort of different results.. you should be using mod instead of divide.. which will be \ 300

Comment: What happens if you replace `/ 300` with `* 0.003333`?

Comment: @krishKM - I think you've got the right idea, but \ (integer division) is not `Mod` (modulus). The difference between SQL Server and Access is that when T-SQL does "regular division" (`/`) on integer values it actually does "integer division" and returns an integer, whereas when Access does "regular division" on integers it returns a floating-point value.

Comment: Thx krish KM, it works perfectly. I Thought "/" was modulo I believe as in SQL Server if i am not wrong. Anyway I did not know that modulo was "\". It works great.

Comment: Thx Gord, very educational

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this for some fixed intervals:

```
SELECT 
    CDate(Int(LAST_TRADE_TIME * 86400 / 300) / 86400 * 300)) AS ConflatedDate, 
    Min(CUR) As MinCur
FROM 
    MYTABLE
GROUP BY 
    CDate(Int(LAST_TRADE_TIME * 86400 / 300) / 86400 * 300))
```

Comment: Yes @Gustav, It works well too (as krish KM proposal). I don't really understand how the group by works though... Thx a lot.

Comment: The `Group By` contains the expression for the _first_ field/coloumn which is not aggregated, thus must be grouped by. The _second_ is aggregated by `Min`.